# How to download and attach file when sending email in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image]

-I want to click the download button and download this bill as pdf as well as I want to attach this pdf in an email.

I use this code-

```
public function details_pdf($id) {
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->load->helper('download');

    $data['invoice_detls'] = $this->user_model->front_get_invoice_details(['front_orders_id'=>$id]);
    $data['items'] = $this->user_model->front_get_ordered_items(['front_dish_invoice_id' => $id]);

    //$data['abstract_message'] = $this->user_model->get_abstract_message(['abstract_id' => $id]);
    //$data['user_details'] = $this->user_model->get_user(['id' => $data['abstract_message'][0]['user_id']]);

    //$data['user_details_member'] = $this->user_model->get_profile_details(['members.userid' => $data['abstract_message'][0]['user_id']]);
    //print_r($data['user_details']);die();

    $customer_name =  $data['invoice_detls'][0]['customer_name'];
    $customer_phone =  $data['invoice_detls'][0]['customer_phone'];

    //load the view and saved it into $html variable
    $html = $this->load->view('front_billing_view', $data, true);
    $time = time();


    //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
    $pdfFilePath = "$customer_name.'_'.$customer_phone.'_'.$time.pdf";

    $this->user_model->update_order(['front_orders_id' => $id],['bill_pdf'=>$pdfFilePath]);

    //load mPDF library
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');

    //generate the PDF from the given html
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

    //download it.
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");

    /*--------------------Mail function Start-----------------------*/
        $order_fetch = $this->user_model->front_get_invoice_details(['front_orders_id' => $id]);

        $email = $order_fetch[0]['customer_email'];
        $pdf_name = $order_fetch[0]['bill_pdf'];
            $config = Array(
               'protocol' => 'smtp',
               'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
               'smtp_port' => 465,
               'smtp_user' => 'noreply@wsdev.in',
               'smtp_pass' => '%KidFlash!2#4%',
               'mailtype' => 'text/html',
               'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
               'charset' => 'utf-8'
            );
            $this->load->library('email');
            $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $from_email = 'noreply@wsdev.in';
            $this->email->from($from_email);
            $this->email->to($email);
            $this->email->subject('Order Delivered');
            $this->email->message('Your Order Successfully Delivered.');                       
            $this->email->attach($pdfFilePath);
            $this->email->send();

    /*--------------------Mail Function End-----------------------*/ 


}
```

This code only downloads the pdf but I can not send the download file as an email for clicking the download button because of this file store into the desktop not in the project folder. how to solve this problem?

Comment: This: `$pdfFilePath = "$customer_name.'_'.$customer_phone.'_'.$time.pdf";` looks very odd. It would literally produce a string looking something like this: `thename.'_'.thephone.'_'.12345.pdf`. That doesn't look like a good filename.

Comment: If you want to reuse the generated PDF, store it in a temp folder on the server and use that to download and add to the email.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Check the manual for the PDF-library you're using.

Comment: This is from the mPDF documentation page [E-mail a PDF file](https://mpdf.github.io/real-life-examples/e-mail-a-pdf-file.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `attach()` method need a full path/name, eg. `/home/user/file.pdf' - [Codeigniter Email Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)

Before generate the pdf document with download option, you could generate the pdf locally then generate the pdf with dowload option.

```
//generate the PDF from the given html
$this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

// save it 
$tmpPdfFile = '/home/user/file.pdf'; // change this acording to your configuration
$mpdf->Output($tmpPdfFile,'F');

//download it.
$this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");


// attach file to mail
 $this->email->attach($tmpPdfFile);
 $this->email->send();

// delete $tmpPdfFile after email send if you don't need it
unlink($tmpPdfFile);
```

Comment: how to save this particular pdf in my server folder?

Comment: Please see in my response, after `// save it` comment

Comment: $tmpPdfFile = '/download/'.$pdfFilePath; // change this acording to your configuration
        $mpdf->Output($tmpPdfFile,'F');
- I add this code. "$pdfFilePath" this is my original file name.downloadis my folder where i want to save.

Comment: And now it's working? I suggest the $tmpPdfFile to be a full path, like c:/temp/my_pdf_file.pdf

Comment: I use <?=site_url('download/'.$pdfFilePath)?> for $tmpPdfFile. but I get null value.I create download folder for save pdf file.

Comment: $this->email->attach() doesn't work with url path. you can use $pdfFilePath = FCPATH . 'file.pdf'; , FCPATH is root of you application

Comment: How would you attach a file dynamically? What I meant is if I want to attach different files to the different instance, how would you do that?

Comment: Keep in mind that you can call `attach()` method multiple times to attach multiple files. You need to generate temporary files with desired filename, attach to mail and delete files after email was sent.